# Is it true that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-3-2z)^n =\frac{1}{2z+4}$ for $z\in\mathbb{C}$, $|-3-2z|<1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, functions, complex-numbers, power-series

This problem requires us to find a power series expression for $\frac{1}{2z+4}$ where $z\in \mathbb{C}$.

---

ANSWER 1:

Let  $S_k=\sum_{n=0}^{k} (-3-2z)^n$. Then we have the following:

$(-3-2z)S_k=(-3-2z)+(-3-2z)^2+...(-3-2z)^{k+1}=S_k-1+(-3-2z)^{k+1} $.

Hence $S_k=\frac{1-(-3-2z)^{k+1}}{1-(-3-2z)}$

So for $|-3-2z|<1$ we have $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-3-2z)^n =\frac{1}{2z+4}$. [ANSWER 1]

---

ANSWER 2:

However, for $|z|<1$, we have $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^n =\frac{1}{1-z}$

Now  $\frac{1}{2z+4}=\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{1-(-\frac{z}{2})}=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-\frac{z}{2})^n$ for $|z|<2$. [ANSWER 2]

---

Are answer 1 and answer 2 for $\frac{1}{2z+4}$ equivalent, or is one correct and the other incorrect?

Comment: I believe that $|\frac{z}{2}|<1$ is equivalent to $|2z|<4$ equivalent to $-3-|2z|<1$, perhaps with a triangular inequality with absolute function to find one relationship with $|-3-2z|$, i guess, sorry. So, i believe they are equivalent.

Comment: Only answer 2 is a power series in $z$.  There may be other series which are legitimate power series in a different variable $w=f(z)$, but unless you're specifically asked for that, a power series should be a power series in the given independent variable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both are correct expansions of the same function, on different domains.

Your Answer 1 has domain centered at $z=-\frac{3}{2}$ and radius $\frac{1}{2}$. Your Answer 2 is the Maclaurin expansion, with domain centered at $z=0$ and radius $2$. (The first domain is a strict subset of the second.)

In general, we can find a Taylor expansion centered at any point $z_0 \neq -2$, with radius of convergence up to the singular point $z=-2$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the other side we have

$\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{-z}{2})^{n}=\frac{1}{2z+4}=\frac{1}{2z+3+1}= \frac{1}{1-(-3-2z)}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-3-2z)^n$ with $|-3-2z|<1$.